# If /store/*/aproduct

Tags: php, if-statement

```
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/store/'.*.'/aproduct')
```

Is that possible? So if I type /store/something/aproduct or /store/abc123/aproduct the if statement happens? The '*' should be everything. Dosent matter if you type cow, 123, lol or youarenice

Comment: Why didn't you ask the quesiton you wanted in the first place? Or use the answers you got there as a basis to work from?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
if ( preg_match('~^/store/[^/]+/aproduct$~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) )
```

Comment: `[^/]+` will give you better performance than the lazy quantifier. This is of course only if `/` is not included in your string `*`. This regex would also match `/store/foo/bar/rab/oof/aproduct`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Ok, you're right - I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use regular expressions for that. Something like this should work:

```
if(preg_match('@^\/store\/.+\/aproduct@', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    // do something
}
```